# Having problems setting up SFML with MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw, sfml

So I've recently transitioned to compiling through the cmd but when I tried to setup SFML, I ran into a problem.

I used this tutorial: http://verra.xyz/howto/sfml.html following it step by step. After I did everything, I got the following error messages after compiling:

> E:\Cpp\Random>g++ sfmlTest.cpp -o hello -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
>
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsfml-graphics
>
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsfml-window
>
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsfml-system
>
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I'd be really thankful if someone was to help me. Cheers!

Comment: Seems your problem is linker paths. You have not told the linker where to look for the sfml compiled libraries. hint: `-L`

Comment: @drescherjm Could you perhaps walk me through setting that up or give me some tips since I'm have little to no knowledge about dealing with the compiler itself. Thanks!

Comment: I believe its `-L folder_containing_sfml_libraries` here is some documentation: https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-l.html